# An inequality concerning formulas and Boolean functions

Tags: lo.logic, computer-science

We define $S(\phi)$ of formula $\phi$ to be the number of computational gates in a minimal $\{\neg, \wedge, \vee\}$-formula computing $\phi$.

**Conjecture.** If $\phi_1(a_{11}, \dots, a_{1y_1})$, $\dots$, $\phi_x(a_{x1}, \dots, a_{xy_x})$ are arbitrary Boolean functions with pairwise disjoint sets of variables, then it follows that$$S\left(\phi_1\left(a_{11}, \dots, a_{1y_1}\right) \oplus \ldots \oplus \phi_x\left(a_{x1}, \dots, a_{xy_x}\right)\right) \ge {1\over2}\sum_{i = 1}^x S(\phi_i).$$Is this true or not? If so, how do we show this? Or does there exist a counterexample?

Comment: What is $\oplus$?

Comment: This does not hold for constant functions.  Gerhard "There's A One Gate Minimum" Paseman, 2017.03.26.

Comment: Gerhard, we had the same idea!

Comment: Why should there be a *logical* gate for a constant function? It is just like hot/cold wire (so, I would say 0 gates). Of course, it depends on how you count, but let's interpret everything in the favor of the poster.

Comment: @fedja The formula $\varphi(x)=x\vee\neg x$ is a constant function. This is why I had said $S(\phi)=2$ in my answer, since it takes two logical operations to make a tautology.

Comment: Yes, but 0/1 (whichever is appropriate) is also a constant function. Anyway, I went to Wikipedia to check what logical operation on Earth may be denoted by $\oplus$ and it looks like it is the addition modulo 2 (XOR). Then there is an obvious candidate for a counterexample though it involves some religious experience (the step any reasonable person will believe that may be extremely hard to justify). I'll still post it in lieu of any better ideas.

Comment: @fedja The OP says that we should represent the Boolean function with a minimal $\{\wedge,\vee,\neg\}$ formula, and so I interpreted the question where $S(\varphi)$ is counting the minimal number of occurences of those logical operations in the minimal such representation of the Boolean function. It takes two such logical connectives to make either $0$ or $1$, with $x\wedge\neg x$ or $x\vee\neg x$, respectively.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I'm not trying to argue. Your way of counting makes perfect sense too but, unless our goal is to dismiss the question with the minimal effort, let us add the word "non-constant" before "Boolean function" :-)

Comment: It would not heart if the Author of the Question were more explicit. Nevertheless, it is quite common to define the complexity of a constant as 0.

Comment: Perhaps complexity function should be better based on the number of appearances of variables in a formula. Then variable v and its negation ~v would each have complexity equal 1.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: the strikethroughs are in response to the followup comments that ensued.

<strike>I believe this is open</strike>.  For simplicity, assume the $\phi$'s are the same function.  It's a bit more standard to write $L(\phi)$ for the minimum formula size of $\phi$.  The original question is whether $L(\oplus_m \circ f) \gtrapprox m L(f)$, where $\oplus_m$ denotes arity-$m$-XOR.  Indeed, one could hope even for $L(\oplus_m \circ f) \gtrapprox m^2 L(f)$, since the formula complexity of $\oplus_m$ is $m^2$.

This stronger (potential) lower bound is presented as a major conjecture (Conjecture 1.10) in the following recent work of Gavinsky, Meir, Weinstein, and Wigderson: http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/GavinskyMeWeWi2016.pdf  The question dates back to Karchmer-Raz-Wigderson'95.

This leaves open the weaker statement $L(\oplus_m \circ f) \gtrapprox m L(f)$ -- basically, what was asked in the original question -- <strike>but my guess is that this is equally unknown</strike>.

One more remark: as noted in the paper above, the desired conjecture *is* true if the XOR operation is replaced by the OR operation.

EDIT: Wegener's observation (see coments) that the desired conjecture holds true for OR seems to apply equally well for XOR, as noted by Fedja.  So it would seem that the answer to the poster's question is positive, even without the factor $1/2$, assuming the $\phi$'s are nonconstant.

Comment: Hi Ryan, is it possible you could include a proof in the OR case?

Comment: The reference is given in the Gavinsky et al paper, to Wegner's book. The proof is short, I believe. I'll write it if I get a chance today.

Comment: *Wegener, sorry for the misspelling.  It is Theorem 2.1.ii in Section 10.2 of this: https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/resources/pdf/cobf.pdf    The theorem statement is "S(f v g) = S(f)+S(g)+1, provided f and g are not constant", where f v g means f(x) v g(y), where x and y are disjoint sets of variables.  The proof goes like this.  Suppose we have a formula for f(x) v g(y) with r leaves.  Plug in an input x that makes f = 0.  We get a formula for g(y), which must have at least S(g)+1 leaves (by definition), and all these leaves are y-variables.  Similarly one can argue that there must be at least..

Comment: .. S(f)+1 many x-variables, by substituting in for y something that makes g = 0.  Thus overall there are at least S(f)+S(g)+2 many leaves, implying S(f v g) >= S(f)+S(g)+1.  The upper bound is obvious.

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell And what's the difference between $\vee$ and $\oplus$ in this proof of the linear bound?. Am I missing something again?

Comment: Good.  It seems the lower bound holds equally well for $\oplus$, therefore answering OP's original question.  The upper bound fails to hold, which I guess is what makes the Gavinsky et al. question interesting.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** As Emil pointed out, that will work for the *circuit* complexity, but not for the *formula* complexity. I apologize for being confused, but still will leave this post just as a curious observation.

Here is a possible candidate for an (interesting) counterexample.

Take some big $y$ and a prime $p$ slightly bigger than $2^y$. Let all $\varphi_j$ be the same and return $0$ if the binary number $\overline{a_1\dots a_y}+1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ and $1$ otherwise.

Let $M$ be the complexity of $\varphi$ and $m$ be the complexity of arithmetic operations (addition and multiplication) modulo $p$.

**Religious dogma:** When $y$ is large, $M/m$ is also large.

If we believe it, then the composite formula can be computed by first multiplying all numbers out, subtracting $1$ and then applying $\varphi$, thus consuming only about $xm+M\ll xM$ gates.

My question is whether we can set up some construction like that staying purely within mathematics.

Comment: This is a great counterexample. Indeed, iterated multiplication modulo $p$ has polynomial-size formulas (being computable in uniform $\mathrm{TC^0}$), whereas this is very unlikely to be true for the Legendre symbol.

Comment: No, wait a minute. This doesn't work. We are talking formula complexity, not circuit complexity. Thus, the "composite formula" is $\varphi$ with every occurrence of a variable replaced with a separate copy of the appropriate multiplication formula. The total size is roughly the *product* of the two formula sizes, not their *sum*.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek What do you mean? Once we have the output of the multiplication ($n$ outgoing wires), we just feed them as inputs of $\varphi$. Also, Legendre symbol is polynomial ($a^{(p-1)/2}\mod p$ computed via the squaring technique), but this requires much more than one multiplication, that's why the dogma.

Comment: Again: these are *formulas*, not circuits. Each gate can be fed as input to another gate only *once*. So, each time the output of the multiplication formula is used, it has to be recomputed. Likewise, the Legendre symbol has polynomial *circuits*, but likely not formulas. A useful equivalent is that a function has poly-size formulas iff it has (bounded fan-in) circuits of logarithmic *depth*.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Argh! You don't allow branching wires!!! You are right then. Of course, I thought of circuits rather than formulas. Thanks for the clarification (once I see the word "gate", I immediately think of a circuit somehow). Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by $\oplus$, but here is a counterexample. Let each $\phi_i(\vec x)$ be a tautology. So $S(\phi_i)=2$. But $\phi_1\oplus\cdots\phi_x$ is also trivial (depending on what you mean by $\oplus$), and so takes just a few operations. But $\frac12\sum_i S(\phi_i)=x$, which can be very large.